# Javascript regex to remove hex bytes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

One way is to have all 255 bytes (`x00 - xFF`) in the pattern:

```
function removeHex(txt) {
   // Assume I have all of them
   return String(txt).replace(/[\x00\x01\x02\x03\xFF]/g, '')
}

removeHex('[\xaa] [\xff]')
>>> '[ª] []'
```

What's a simpler way to match those literal hex bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a character class that matches your definition of "hex bytes". Something like

```
/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xA0]+/g
```

would probably do the trick... until you encounter characters outside `C0 Controls and Basic Latin` (`U+0000`–`U+007F`) and `C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement` (`U+0080`–`U+00FF`).

Try something like...

```js
function tidy(s) {
  const tidy = typeof s === 'string'
    ? s.replace( /[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xA0]+/g, '' )
    : s ;
  return tidy;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete example that would match the following string? `'abc [\x00] [\xAA] [\xF0] [\xFA]'.replace(/<some pattern>/g, '')` expected output is `'abc [] [] [] []'`. Your example only matches `\x00`.

Comment: @SnakeVerde — Added an example for you.

Comment: That's because those are not "hex characters": *you* need to define the character set that match what you want to remove. `U+00AA` is a non-breaking space character. `U+00F0` is the lower-case letter 'eth' ('ð'). And `U+00FA` is a lower-case 'u' _avec accent aigu_ ('ú'). Not "hex characters". Perfectly acceptable printing characters. See the Unicode Code Charts for details at https://unicode.org/charts/ (in particular, _Basic Latin (ASCII)_ and _Latin-1 Supplement_). Only you can define what characters you want to strip out.

Comment: My regular expression removes all the non-printing control characters in the space `U+0000` through `U+00FF`. If you want to be pedantic, though, it should probably not remove HT (`U+0009`, horizontal tab), CR (`U+000D`, carriage return), and LF (`U+000A`, line feed)... for obvious reasons.